# Why .navbar-dark doesn't work (Bootstrap v5.2)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

For some strange reasons that I don't understand, navbar-dark doesn't change text color in the nav. Why it can be so? Thanks in advance!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">Something</nav>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow the html structure given by bootstrap 5. you need to add `navbar-brand` class to the text. you can read more [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <span  class="navbar-brand">Something</span>
  
   </nav>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably download some theme from Bootstrap, change the color in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Yes like the guy above me said, if you downloaded a theme then the proper answer is to change color in CSS class  **navbar-dark**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you must write like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <span  class="navbar-brand">Something</span>
</nav>
```